# How to Hide parent DIV if all child Div are hidden (display:none)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this HTML block

```
<div class="abc">
<div class="xyz" style="display: none;">{.......}</div>
<div class="xyz" style="display: none;">{.......}</div>
<div class="xyz" style="display: none;">{.......}</div>
<div class="xyz" style="display: none;">{.......}</div>
<div class="xyz" style="display: none;">{.......}</div>
</div>
```

So if All child div are hidden then i want to hide parent div (.ABC) on some JS action.

Thanks

Comment: show us what have you tried so far

Comment: Do you hide children dynamically using javascript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Loop through all children dom elements to check for the display style and update the status

```js
$(function(){
  var hid = true;

$('button').click(function(){
$('.xyz').each(function(index,item){
    console.log($(item).css("display"));
      if($(item).css("display") != "none") {
        hid = false;
      }
  }).promise().done(function(){
    if(hid == true) {
      console.log("true");
      $('.abc').hide();
    }
  });
})  
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="abc">
<div class="xyz" style="display: none;">{.......}</div>
<div class="xyz" style="display: none;">{.......}</div>
<div class="xyz" style="display: none;">{.......}</div>
<div class="xyz" style="display: none;">{.......}</div>
<div class="xyz" style="display: none;">{.......}</div>
</div>
<button type="button">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`:visible`](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) pseudo-class selector and show based on the visible div's count. Where you can use [`toggle()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/) method to toggle the visibility based on a boolean value.

```js
$('.abc').toggle($('.xyz:visible').length != 0);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="abc">
  <div class="xyz" style="display: none;">{.......}</div>
  <div class="xyz" style="display: none;">{.......}</div>
  <div class="xyz" style="display: none;">{.......}</div>
  <div class="xyz" style="display: none;">{.......}</div>
  <div class="xyz" style="display: none;">{.......}</div>
</div>
```

---

If there are multiple elements use [`each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) method and iterate over them.

```js
$('.abc').each(function() {
  return $(this).toggle($('.xyz:visible', this).length != 0);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="abc">
  <div class="xyz" style="display: none;">{.......}</div>
  <div class="xyz" style="display: none;">{.......}</div>
  <div class="xyz" style="display: none;">{.......}</div>
  <div class="xyz" style="display: none;">{.......}</div>
  <div class="xyz" style="display: none;">{.......}</div>
</div>
<div class="abc">
  <div class="xyz">{.......}</div>
  <div class="xyz" style="display: none;">{.......}</div>
  <div class="xyz" style="display: none;">{.......}</div>
  <div class="xyz" style="display: none;">{.......}</div>
  <div class="xyz" style="display: none;">{.......}</div>
</div>
<div class="abc">
  <div class="xyz" style="display: none;">{.......}</div>
  <div class="xyz" style="display: none;">{.......}</div>
  <div class="xyz" style="display: none;">{.......}</div>
  <div class="xyz" style="display: none;">{.......}</div>
  <div class="xyz" style="display: none;">{.......}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var allHidden = true;

$('.xyz').each(function(){
 if($(this).is(':visible'))
 {
  allHidden = false;
  return false; //break out of each looping function as soon as first visible div is found
 }
});

if(allHidden)
 $('.abc').css('display','none');
else
 $('.abc').css('display','block');
```

Here is [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/aaav8bc1/)

Answer (score 1):

One approach, and here we're using a `click` Event since you've given no information as to how you're hiding the child elements, is the following:

```
function toggleOnHiddenChildren() {

  // here we set the the CSS 'display' property
  // via the HTMLElement.style interface,
  // using a conditional ('ternary') operator:
  this.style.display = 

    // here we use Array.prototype.slice(), along
    // with Function.prototype.call(), to convert
    // the NodeList of the 'this.children' into an
    // Array, and then use Array.prototype.every()
    // to iterate over that Array in order to test
    // whether all elements match the supplied
    // test:
    Array.prototype.slice.call(this.children).every(function(child) {

    // we're using window.getComputedStyle() in order
    // to obtain the CSS display property-value regardless
    // of whether the style was set as an inline style
    // (as it would be if directly applied by JavaScript)
    // or via a stylesheet (as it would be if the style was
    // applied via the use of a class-name).
    // if the display property-value is 'none' (the element
    // is hidden) then this returns Boolean true, if all elements
    // return true then the Array.prototype.every() method
    // also returns true, which then causes the display of
    // the 'this' element to be set to 'none', otherwise to
    // 'block':
    return window.getComputedStyle(child, null).display === 'none';
  }) ? 'none' : 'block';
}

// creating an Array of the <div> elements with the class-
// name of 'abc':
var abcElements = Array.prototype.slice.call(
    document.querySelectorAll('div.abc')
);

// iterating over the Array of elements using
// Array.prototype.forEach():
abcElements.forEach(function(abc){
  // 'abc' : a reference to the current element of the
  //         Array of elements over which we're iterating.

  // here we add an event-listener for the 'click' event
  // which calls the named function as the event-handler
  // (note the deliberate lack of parentheses):
  abc.addEventListener('click', toggleOnHiddenChildren);
});
```

```js
function toggleOnHiddenChildren() {
  this.style.display = Array.prototype.slice.call(this.children).every(function(child) {
    return window.getComputedStyle(child, null).display === 'none';
  }) ? 'none' : 'block';
}

var abcElements = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('div.abc'));

abcElements.forEach(function(abc) {
  abc.addEventListener('click', toggleOnHiddenChildren);
});
```

```css
.abc {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  height: 2em;
  background-color: #f90;
}
```

```html
<div class="abc">
  <div class="xyz" style="display: none;">{.......}</div>
  <div class="xyz" style="display: none;">{.......}</div>
  <div class="xyz" style="display: none;">{.......}</div>
  <div class="xyz" style="display: none;">{.......}</div>
  <div class="xyz" style="display: none;">{.......}</div>
</div>
```

Note that, in compliant (ES2015) browsers, the use of:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(NodeList);
```

can be replaced with:

```
Array.from(NodeList);
```

If, of course, you'd prefer this function to run on page-load, while still also responding to the same event as before, we can modify the call to `Array.prototype.forEach()` to the following, which directly triggers that `event`; although this does require us to create a new event using the Event constructor:

```
var clickEvent = new Event('click'); 

abcElements.forEach(function(abc) {
  abc.addEventListener('click', toggleOnHiddenChildren);
  abc.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
});
```

```js
function toggleOnHiddenChildren() {
  this.style.display = Array.prototype.slice.call(this.children).every(function(child) {
    return window.getComputedStyle(child, null).display === 'none';
  }) ? 'none' : 'block';
}

var abcElements = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('div.abc')),
  clickEvent = new Event('click');

abcElements.forEach(function(abc) {
  abc.addEventListener('click', toggleOnHiddenChildren);
  abc.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
});
```

```css
.abc {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  height: 2em;
  background-color: #f90;
}
```

```html
<div class="abc">
  <div class="xyz" style="display: none;">{.......}</div>
  <div class="xyz" style="display: none;">{.......}</div>
  <div class="xyz" style="display: none;">{.......}</div>
  <div class="xyz" style="display: none;">{.......}</div>
  <div class="xyz" style="display: none;">{.......}</div>
</div>
```

Or we could simply use an Immediately-Invoked Function Expression ("IIFE"), a form in which the browser will execute the function as soon as it's encountered:

```
// the 'elements' argument is passed in from the 'external'
// function-following parentheses:

(function (elements) {

  // iterating over the Array of elements passed to
  // the anonymous function using Array.prototype.forEach():
  elements.forEach(function(abc){
    // 'abc' : reference to the current element of the
    // Array of elements over which we're iterating.

    // setting the 'display' property-value as before,
    // again using Array.prototype.every() to check that
    // all child elements are 'display: none'
    abc.style.display = Array.prototype.slice.call(abc.children).every(function(child){
      return window.getComputedStyle(child, null).display === 'none';
    }) ? 'none' : 'block';
  });

})(Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('div.abc')));
```

```js
(function(elements) {

  elements.forEach(function(abc) {
    abc.style.display = Array.prototype.slice.call(abc.children).every(function(child) {
      return window.getComputedStyle(child, null).display === 'none';
    }) ? 'none' : 'block';
  });

})(Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('div.abc')));
```

```css
.abc {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  height: 2em;
  background-color: #f90;
}
```

```html
<div class="abc">
  <div class="xyz" style="display: none;">{.......}</div>
  <div class="xyz" style="display: none;">{.......}</div>
  <div class="xyz" style="display: none;">{.......}</div>
  <div class="xyz" style="display: none;">{.......}</div>
  <div class="xyz" style="display: none;">{.......}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var children = $(".abc").find($('.xyz'));
  if($(children).is(":hidden")){
    $(".abc").hide();
  }
  else{
    $(".abc").show();
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.abc').css('display', 'none') // .abc if set to display none

$('.abc .xyz').each(function(i,e){  //looping inner divs
 if($(this).css('display') === 'block'){ //checks if any inner div is block then parent div set to block otherwise it remains display none
  $('.abc').css('display', 'block')
}
});
```

Comment: It's good practice on Stack Overflow to add an explanation as to why your solution should work. For more information read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$('#btn_hide').click(function(){
var status = 0;
$('.xyz').each(function(){
 if($(this).is(":visible")){
   alert('Do not hide abc');
   status = 0;
 } else 
 {
  status = 1;
 }
})
if(status == 1){
$('.abc').hide();
} else
{
$('.abc').show();
}
})

<div class="abc">asdas
<div class="xyz" style="display: none;">{.......}</div>
<div class="xyz" style="display: none;">{.......}</div>
<div class="xyz" style="display: none;">{.......}</div>
<div class="xyz" style="display: none;">{.......}</div>
<div class="xyz" style="display: none;">{.......}</div>
</div>

<input type="button" id="btn_hide" value="Hide">
```

Working demo :

https://jsfiddle.net/qrd64nxh/

Answer (score 0):

You can make a check with JavaScript, if all the elements with the `xyz` class have a style atribute of display: none, then hide the parent element, otherwise do nothing.

```js
if ($('.xyz').css('display') == 'none'){
   $('.abc').hide();
}
```

```css
.abc{
  width: 100px;
  height 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="abc">
ABC DIV
<div class="xyz" style="display: none;">{.......}</div>
<div class="xyz" style="display: none;">{.......}</div>
<div class="xyz" style="display: none;">{.......}</div>
<div class="xyz" style="display: none;">{.......}</div>
<div class="xyz" style="display: none;">{.......}</div>
</div>
```

The advantage of this is that you can make some simple extra if statements, for the .hide() of visibility: hidden properties.

You can change one of the elements from display: none to something different and the `abc` parent will show.

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/jj6mpa59/)